# Substrate Sidecar Custom Type Issue

Tags: api, sidecar, custom-types, types

I'm wiring up the substrate sidecar to a chain which has some custom type and some out of date types (as compared to current) such as AccountInfo.
I've found that it uses the older `AccountInfoWithRefCount` definition. Accordingly I created a json file as follows:

```
{
  "types": {
    "AccountInfo": "AccountInfoWithRefCount"
  }
}
```

I then used the environment variable `SAS_SUBSTRATE_TYPES=/custom_types/types.json` (obviously with the correct volume mapping done) to fire up the container.
The logs from the container indicate that it is using the custom type file... however no behavioral change is observed. The same decode error is present before and after:

```
"Unable to decode storage system.account:: createType(AccountInfo):: {\"nonce\":\"Index\",\"consumers\":\"RefCount\",\"providers\":\"RefCount\",\"sufficients\":\"RefCount\",\"data\":\"AccountData\"}:: Decoded input doesn't match input, received … (72 bytes), created … (80 bytes)"
```

Am I doing something wrong with the type file or is the sidecar not honoring it in some way? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geez... remove the outer `types` property so just have:

```
{
  "AccountInfo": "AccountInfoWithRefCount"
}
```

And everything works... maybe this will help someone else.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the answer. :)